# Toolbar issue with ActionSheet

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following example code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailViewToolbarBug()) {
                Text("Unknown")
            }
        }
    }
}
struct DetailViewToolbarBug: View {
    @State private var showActionSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailViewToolbarBug()) {
                Text("Unknown")
            }
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("Optionen"),
                buttons: [
                    .default(Text("Add"), action: {
                    })  
            ])
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                
                Button(action: {
                    showActionSheet = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

The issue: If you navigate in two or more times and then open the action sheet, the back button (will have the name `Detail` in it) will disappear and not come back again.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a SwiftUI bug and worth submitting feedback to Apple.

Temporary workaround is to use old `.navigationBarItems`. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
  // ... other code
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                 Button(action: {
                      showActionSheet = true
                 }) {
                      Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                 }
        )
//        .toolbar {
//            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
//
//                Button(action: {
//                    showActionSheet = true
//                }) {
//                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
//                }
//            }
//        }
```

Comment: Thank you. Good idea to use the old way, its working. File send a FB to Apple