# SwiftUI Triggering second ActionSheet from within ActionSheet only working on second try

Tags: swift, swiftui

Seems like it might be a SwiftUI bug.

I've got the following code to handle two different ActionSheets:

```
import SwiftUI

enum Sheets: Identifiable {
    case first, second

    var id: Int {
        self.hashValue
    }
}

struct EditMenu: View {
    @State var activeSheet: Sheets?

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { activeSheet = .first }) {
            Text("Open Menu")
        }.padding(.top, 10).padding(.leading, 10).padding(.bottom, 10)
        .actionSheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
            return sheetContent(item: item)
        }
    }

    private func sheetContent(item: Sheets) -> ActionSheet {
        switch item {
        case .first:
            return ActionSheet(
                title: Text("Menu 1"),
                buttons: [
                    .default(Text("Open Second Menu"), action: { activeSheet = .second }),
                    .cancel()
                ]
            )
        case .second:
            return ActionSheet(
                title: Text("Menu 2"),
                buttons: [
                    .default(Text("Sweet")),
                    .cancel()
                ]
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Pretty straightforwards, I am setting the `activeSheet` to the `.second` sheet from within the first.

The thing that's strange about this is it only works on the second attempt:

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate with the code provided. Maybe it has something to do with the view hierarchy that it's in? I would guess it's a timing issue and you can probably get away with adding a slight delay to the 2nd sheet. Something like: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { activeSheet = .second }

Comment: @nicksarno i had tried adding a delay in the same way, unfortunately did not fix the issue. It might be because this `EditMenu` view is initialized like so `.navigationBarItems(trailing: EditMenu())`, so it's in a navigationBar. This method for doing so of course is deprecated but the modern way:  `.toolbar { ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) { EditMenu(vm: vm) }}` is currently experiencing a bug https://stackoverflow.com/q/64464762/117554 that doesn't allow you to open an ActionSheet from the toolbar.